# Boruta test and naive bayes classification

Tags: r, naive-bayes, boruta

I am currently using Boruta  to test which feature is the most important to be used in my model development. For example, I have 3 features(X,Y,Z).Boruta test give the highest importance is Z. However when I test the feature with naive Bayes classifier, feature X is better performance. May I know why and how this situation happen?

Answer (score 2):

Boruta uses Random Forest to determine feature importance. The features which are "important" in a Random Forest model may not be the most important in a Bayes model.